# Wrapping a GridView with custom controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My aim is to create a server control which inherits from a GridView and outputs the basic output wrapped in external markup, including other controls.  For example, the output will look something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="summaryContent" />
  </div>
  <div id="gridViewWrapper">
    <asp:GridView id="standardGrid />
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="footerContent" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Normally, I would override `CreateChildControls` and alter the child control collection appropriately, but this has a number of difficulties for gridviews:

1. `LoadViewState()` will fail if I've altered the control
   collection, so I can't use `CreateChildControls`.
2. DataBinding wipes the control collection.
3. The GridView will throw an exception on Render if the ChildTable
   isn't the first item in the control hierarchy.

My solution therefore has been:

```
Public Class SearchResultsControl_2
    Inherits PagingSortingGridView ' Note that this inherits from GridView with custom paging/sorting implementation
    Implements INamingContainer

#Region "Child Controls"
  ...
#End Region

#Region "LifeCycle Events"

    ''' <summary>Loading databound fields from viewstate will only work if we have not created the custom control hierarchy.
    ''' Therefore we load viewstate; without the custom controls, and then again; with them.</summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(savedState As Object)
        MyBase.LoadViewState(savedState)

        CreateCustomControlHierarchy()

        MyBase.LoadViewState(savedState)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>As Me.DataBind will wipe the custom control collection, we need to recreate the custom control hierarchy.</summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDataBound(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDataBound(e)

        CreateCustomControlHierarchy()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>During render, the GridView will not render unless it's the only controls in the Me.Controls() collection.</summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        ' So, first we clear the control hierarchy
        Me.Controls.Remove(_searchResultsControl)

        ' Then we move any existing controls from the grid section wrapper to the main control collection
        Dim gridSectionControls As IEnumerable(Of Control) = From ctrl As Control In _gridSection.Controls
        For Each ctrl As Control In gridSectionControls
            _gridSection.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
            Me.Controls.Add(ctrl)
        Next

        ' Now that everything is in the right place, we should be able to render the base object to a temporary holder ...
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter(sb)
        Dim htw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        MyBase.Render(htw)

        ' This can then be set as the innerhtml of the gridsection and the control tree wiped ...
        _gridSection.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
        Next

        ' Then we simply re-add the custom hierarchy and render as normal.
        Me.Controls.Add(_searchResultsControl)
        _searchResultsControl.RenderControl(writer)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>Sets up the finalised control hierarchy.</summary>
    Protected Sub CreateCustomControlHierarchy()
        ' If _searchResultsControl is already part of the control collection we do not need to recreate the collection (in fact, doing so would cause an infinite loop).
        If Me.Controls.Contains(_searchResultsControl) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' If there are any other controls in the collection, they are the GridView control collection, which should be moved to the _gridSection wrapper.
        For Each ctrl As Control In GetBaseGridviewControls()
            Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)

            _gridSection.Controls.Add(ctrl)
        Next

        _searchResultsControl.Controls.Add(_headersTable)
        _searchResultsControl.Controls.Add(_summarySection)
        _searchResultsControl.Controls.Add(_gridSection)
        _searchResultsControl.Controls.Add(_footerSection)

        _footerSection.Controls.Add(_itemCountWrapper)
        _itemCountWrapper.Controls.Add(_itemCount)
        _footerSection.Controls.Add(_footerPanel)

        Me.Controls.Add(_searchResultsControl)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Helper functions"
    ''' <summary>Returns a list of all the controls on Mybase.Controls, which can be used to move the basic items around.</summary>
    Protected Function GetBaseGridviewControls() As List(Of Control)
        Dim retVal As New List(Of Control)

        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            retVal.Add(ctrl)
        Next

        Return retVal
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this which will allow for more maintainable and understandable code.  I'm not happy that I'll be leaving code which might be hard to penetrate for future developers.

For legacy reasons, it's NOT possible to simply create a new control which wraps a GridView more intelligently. It must inherit GridView.
Allowed:

```
<myCode:SearchResultsControl AllowPaging="True">
  <summary>Text Here </summary>
  <Columns> ... </Columns>
  <footer>Text Here</footer>
</myCode:SearchResultsControl>
```

Not Allowed:

```
<myCode: SearchResultsControl>
  <summary>Text here</summary
  <Grid AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns> ... </Columns>
  </Grid>
</myCode: SearchResultsControl/
```

Comment: have you looked into a repeater?

Comment: That wouldn't work for our purposes as we need to simply swap out existing gridviews with the new control, including paging and sorting functionality, plus the ability for our library functions which deal with gridviews to operate seamlessly on the wrapped control.

Comment: I almost suggested that you create your own custom GridView, so that everything works the same except for the output to the page is the way you want it, but it looks like that is what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it.  I'm just trying to avoid having to re-implement EVERYTHING from the basic GridView, or without forwarding EVERYTHING from the basic Gridview explicitly.

Comment: I have never done anything like what you are trying to do before so I am not sure, I think as long as you inherit it and make sure to implement everything that you need you should be fine.